# SQL pattern search

Tags: sql, db2

What 'where' stmt can I use to locate and return values from field cfmesg where the field content is a number followed by hyphen?

```
sample data 
087-2-1-11
56-080
040-4-2-60
```

Comment: Depends on your rdbms. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Comment: Data stored in DB2

Comment: Cool, please tag it with `DB2`, the suggested approach to this differs very much depending on your rdbms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `REGEXP_LIKE` and use a regular expression to find that pattern:

```
WITH YOUR_TABLE AS (
  SELECT '087-2-1-11' AS CFMESG 
  FROM sysibm.sysdummy1
  UNION 
  SELECT '56-080'  
  FROM sysibm.sysdummy1
  UNION 
  SELECT 'abcd'  
  FROM sysibm.sysdummy1
) 
SELECT * FROM YOUR_TABLE
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(CFMESG, '\d-')
```

| CFMESG |
| --- |
| 087-2-1-11 |
| 56-080 |

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/l9hKI_DD)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this query

Select  * From [TableName] Where [ColumnName]  LIKE '%[0-9]-%'

"[0-9]-" will look for numbers followed by a hyphen.

Comment: I don't think that works. LIKE does not use regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it depends on what you are looking for.  If you want to find all lines with a '-' in the value then you would run something like this:

```
select * from table where locate('-', cfmesg) > 1
```

If you are looking for something more specific where the beginning part only contains numbers then you'll want something like this:

```
select * from table where REGEXP_LIKE(cfmesg, '^\d+-')
```